# Comment (or answer) notifications in the global inbox should include the author's username

Tags: feature-request, status-review, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I would like to see who left a comment in my global inbox like this:

[image]

And also for answers:

[image]

(Except, of course, I would like the actual commentor's name, not "The Person Who Left The Comment".)

Could this be considered, or possibly even implemented?

Comment: The picture of merged "2 comments" is not a good example, but for a single comment it would make sense.

Comment: @TLama I now have a much better picture.

Comment: This can be also applied to answers, if we're at it. Right now only chat messages notifications show who left the message.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the features in [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091) :) (though having it implemented natively is always best!)